# Why do I get "Attempt to add with overflow" when I'm encoding a number in a String?

Tags: rust

My encoding function is this one:

```rust
fn encode_login(packet: &str) {
    let bytes = packet.as_bytes();
    for (i, &element) in bytes.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("Index: {}, Byte: {}", i, &element);
        let decoded = (element ^ 0xC3) + 0xF;
        println!("Decoded Byte: {}", decoded);
    }
}

fn main() {
    // let packet = "0123456789"; // Doesn't work
    let packet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; // Work

    encode_login(packet);
}
```

When I use letters, the program encrypts it well, but when I put a number, it panics. I don't know why, I'm newbie in Rust, so maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: `(element ^ 0xC3) + 0xF` can indeed overflow, although it depends on what the elements are. Please provide a proper [mre] that fully reproduces the problem. If it can be reproduced in the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org), that would also be better.

Comment: @E_net4ofthedownvotebrigade Ok, I reproduced it in Rust Playground.
Here's the link:https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=734219ab6b68bc6c7a6a9c8ef05f2648

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include any new pieces of information, including the code which calls that function with the example string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust mathematical operators will panic on overflow in debug mode. This is great in most cases, but not what you want in this kind of low-level operations on bytes.

In your case, this method will panic for the character `1`. Indeed, this character's byte value is `0x31` and:

```
0x31 ^ 0xC3 = 0xf2
0xf2 + 0xF = 0x101 // bigger than a byte!
```

For this kind of operations, Rust provides two convenient ways:

- The [`Wrapping` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.Wrapping.html) is a [wrapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library) for another type, that will make all of its operations wrap instead of panic.
- The [`wrapping_*` methods (eg. `wrapping_add`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html#method.wrapping_add) are method with explicit wrapping semantic. There are also `checked_*`, `overflowing_*` and `saturating_*` methods, which are all useful depending on the use case, but don't have a wrapper type.

Therefore, in you case, you can simply use `wrapping_add` instead of `+`.